# Can I dynamically register objects to proxy with a multiprocessing BaseManager?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing

There are plenty of examples of using a multiprocessing BaseManager-derived class to register a method for returning a queue handle proxy, that clients can then use to pull/put from the queue.

This is great, but I have a different scenario - what if the number of queues that I need to proxy changes in response to outside events? What I really want is to proxy a method that returns a specific queue given a UID.

I tried this out but I couldn't get it to work, it appears that the only things that are available are what is registered with the class before the object is instantiated. I'm unable to `BaseManager.register("my-new-queue", lambda: queue.Queue)` once I've already instantiated an instance of that class and caused it to run.

Is there any way around this? It feels to me like we should be able to dynamically handle this

Answer (score 1):

The registration is most important in the "server" process where the callable will actually get called. Registering a callable in a "client" process only adds that typeid (the string you pass to register) as a method to the manager class. The rub is that running the server blocks, preventing you from registering new callables, and it occurs in another process making it further difficult to modify the registry.

I've been tinkering with this a little while... imao `managers` are cursed.. I think your prior question would also be answered (aside from our discussion in the comments) by the thing that solved it. Basically python attempts to be a little bit secure about not sending around the `authkey` parameter for proxied objects, but it stumbles sometimes (particularly with nested proxies). The fix is to set the default authkey for the process `mp.current_process().authkey = b'abracadabra'` which is used as the fallback when `authkey=None` (https://bugs.python.org/issue7503)

Here's my full testing script which is derived from the remote manager example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager). Basically I create a shared dict to hold shared queues:

```py
#server process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, DictProxy
from multiprocessing import current_process
from queue import Queue
queues = {} #dict[uuid, Queue]
class QueueManager(BaseManager): 
    pass
QueueManager.register('new_queue', callable=Queue)
QueueManager.register('get_queues', callable=lambda:queues, proxytype=DictProxy)
m = QueueManager(address=('localhost', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
current_process().authkey = b'abracadabra'
s = m.get_server()
s.serve_forever()


#process A
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from multiprocessing import current_process
class QueueManager(BaseManager): 
    pass
QueueManager.register('new_queue')
QueueManager.register('get_queues')
m = QueueManager(address=('localhost', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
m.connect()
current_process().authkey = b'abracadabra'
queues_dict = m.get_queues()
queues_dict['my_uuid'] = m.new_queue()
queues_dict['my_uuid'].put("this is a test")


#process B
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from multiprocessing import current_process
class QueueManager(BaseManager): 
    pass
QueueManager.register('new_queue')
QueueManager.register('get_queues')
m = QueueManager(address=('localhost', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
m.connect()
current_process().authkey = b'abracadabra'
queues_dict = m.get_queues()
print(queues_dict['my_uuid'].get())
```

#### EDIT:

Regarding the comments: "`get_queue` take the UUID and return the specific queue" the modification is simple, and does not involve nested proxies thereby avoiding the digest auth issue:

```py
#server process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from collections import defaultdict
from queue import Queue
queues = defaultdict(Queue)
class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
QueueManager.register('get_queue', callable=lambda uuid:queues[uuid])
m = QueueManager(address=('localhost', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
s = m.get_server()
s.serve_forever()

#process A
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
QueueManager.register('get_queue')
m = QueueManager(address=('localhost', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
m.connect()
m.get_queue("my_uuid").put("this is a test")

#process B
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
QueueManager.register('get_queue')
m = QueueManager(address=('localhost', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
m.connect()
print(m.get_queue("my_uuid").get())
```

Comment: Amazing! I tried exactly this (a proxied dictionary mapping UUID to `Queue` but I kept getting serialization errors with the queues, specifically "unable to serialize type _threading.Lock". Let me try this out, I really appreciate all your help here!

Comment: Ah, so one of the things that I was doing wrong was I was trying to make the `get_queues` function take the `uuid` and return just the queue in question, but here you have the registered function return the entire dictionary and just have the client pull from it the specific key it's interested in. Would it work to make `get_queues` parameterized on `my_uuid`?

Comment: edit: I take back the note about modifying the "registry" from a thread. The server splits off a separate process, so a copy is made at that point, which can no longer be mutated..

Comment: Skipping the shared dict isn't that bad either (actually without the nested proxies, I didn't run into the digest auth problem): see edit..

Answer (score 0):

Aaron's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72091025/16310741) is perhaps the simplest way here, where you share a dictionary and store the queues in that shared dictionary. However, it does not answer the problem of not being able to update the methods on a manager once it has started. Therefore, here is a more complete solution, less verbose than it's alternative, where you can update the registry even after the server has started:

```
from queue import Queue
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager, Server, State, dispatch
from multiprocessing.context import ProcessError


class UpdateServer(Server):
    public = ['shutdown', 'create', 'accept_connection', 'get_methods',
              'debug_info', 'number_of_objects', 'dummy', 'incref', 'decref', 'update_registry']

    def update_registry(self, c, registry):
        with self.mutex:
            self.registry.update(registry)

    def get_server(self):

        if self._state.value != State.INITIAL:
            if self._state.value == State.STARTED:
                raise ProcessError("Already started server")
            elif self._state.value == State.SHUTDOWN:
                raise ProcessError("Manager has shut down")
            else:
                raise ProcessError(
                    "Unknown state {!r}".format(self._state.value))
        return self._Server(self._registry, self._address,
                            self._authkey, self._serializer)


class UpdateManager(SyncManager):

    _Server = UpdateServer

    def update_registry(self):
        assert self._state.value == State.STARTED, 'server not yet started'
        conn = self._Client(self._address, authkey=self._authkey)
        try:
            dispatch(conn, None, 'update_registry', (type(self)._registry, ), {})
        finally:
            conn.close()


class MyQueue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.initialized = False
        self.q = None

    def initialize(self):
        self.q = Queue()

    def __call__(self):
        if not self.initialized:
            self.initialize()
            self.initialized = True
        return self.q


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create an object of wrapper class, note that we do not initialize the queue right away (it's unpicklable)
    queue = MyQueue()

    manager = UpdateManager()
    manager.start()

    # If you register new typeids, then call update_registry. The method_to_typeid parameter maps the __call__ method to
    # return a proxy of the queue instead since Queues are not picklable
    UpdateManager.register('uuid', queue, method_to_typeid={'__call__': 'Queue'})
    manager.update_registry()

    # Once the object is stored in the manager process, now we can safely initialize the queue and share
    # it among processes. Initialization is implicit when we call uuid() if it's not already initialized
    q = manager.uuid()

    q.put('bye')
    print(q.get())
```

Over here, `UpdateServer` and `UpdateManager` add support for method `update_registry` which informs the server if any new typeid's are registered with the manager. `MyQueue` is simply a wrapper class to return the new queues registered if called directly. While it's functionally similar to registering `lambda : queue`, the wrapper is necessary because lamdba functions are not picklable and the server process is being started in a new process here (rather than doing `server.serve_forever()` in the main process, but you can do that too if you want).

So, you can now register typeids even after the manager process is running, just make sure to call the `update_registry` function right after. This function call will even work if you are starting the server in the main process itself (by using `serve_forever`, like in Aaron's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72091025/16310741)) and connecting to it from another process using `manager.connect`.